# Find empty folders in subfolders with certain name?

Tags: python, glob

All the subfolders have the same folders with same names.
I want to check which subfolders named dbound are empty in all the directories inside a main folder as in the example.

About half of the folders with that name are empty. How to find out which?
I tried this:

```python
from glob import glob

for i in  glob(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\files1' + '**/*/*/*', recursive=True):
    print (i)

    if os.listdir(i) == []:
        print ("Empty")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob` can return directories *and* files. Check if entry is a directory before testing it. And to test the name use `os.path.basename`

```
if os.path.basename(i) == "dbound" and os.path.isdir(i) and not os.listdir(i):
    print ("{} is Empty".format(i))
```

I would prefer `os.walk` (at least directories are filtered out, and files are ignored):

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\files1'):
   for d in dirs:
       if d=="dbound" and not os.listdir(os.path.join(root,d)):
           print("empty dbound: {}".format(os.path.join(root,d)))
```

Both solutions work, but somehow are unsatisfactory because you're scanning the disk twice (`glob`/`os.walk` and `os.listdir`)

To avoid scanning twice, you'd have to store the result in dictionary/defaultdict and count the files in each dir, filter the ones with no file in it. More complex. Do it only if disk performance matters.

Comment: check for folders named `dbound` .How do I do that?

Comment: sorry, missed a part of your question. Edited

Comment: So I do the glob line as it is and then put this code? I tried it but doesn't return anything although they are empty dbound folders?Keep in mind that the dbound folders are subfolders.

Comment: try the `os.walk` version too it's cleaner and works on old versions of python (more portable). I think there's a typo in the path: `glob(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\files1' + '**/*/*/*', recursive=True):` makes your pattern `r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\files1**/*/*/*'`